# why i can't access and can't delete cookie with php in different browser

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, cookies

I'm running a website in my own computer(with apache and php5.2) for developing, when I login user in the website(which will write a cookie) with IE, I can't logout. when I login with Firefox or chrome, the cookie was written in subdomain, which means I can't get the cookie.

but when I write the cookie, I'm pretty sure that I have set the path to '/' and domain to '.domain.com'.

Anyone have meet this problem?

so far I guess the problem maybe within the php configuration or apache conf.

Comment: Can you post some your cookie setting/deleting code? This will help us identify the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers don´t share cookies, you can´t access a IE cookie from Firefox.

Comment: That answers the question implied by the title but that's not really the question he's asking. He's asking: "Why isn't my code working in any browser?"